# Solr and stopped

Tags: java, solr, garbage-collection, apache-zookeeper

I have 5 nodes of Solr with an embedded zookeeper.

Some days ago, one node show me this **error.**

```
019-10-08T09:32:54.335-0300: 5849301,632: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0,1014562 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0,0810962 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=17052 (full 7):
 par new generation   total 6116736K, used 4972949K [0x00007fbac8000000, 0x00007fbc88000000, 0x00007fbcc8000000)
  eden space 4893440K,  99% used [0x00007fbac8000000, 0x00007fbbf2aba0f0, 0x00007fbbf2ac0000)
  from space 1223296K,   6% used [0x00007fbbf2ac0000, 0x00007fbbf786b688, 0x00007fbc3d560000)
  to   space 1223296K,   0% used [0x00007fbc3d560000, 0x00007fbc3d560000, 0x00007fbc88000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 22020096K, used 4745845K [0x00007fbcc8000000, 0x00007fc208000000, 0x00007fc2c8000000)
 Metaspace       used 61660K, capacity 64298K, committed 64804K, reserved 65536K
2019-10-08T09:32:54.884-0300: 5849302,181: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-10-08T09:32:54.885-0300: 5849302,182: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 1127389592 bytes, new threshold 8 (max 8)
- age   1:   43158120 bytes,   43158120 total
- age   2:   10153136 bytes,   53311256 total
- age   3:   21235976 bytes,   74547232 total
- age   4:   10412792 bytes,   84960024 total
- age   5:    2892856 bytes,   87852880 total
- age   6:     852384 bytes,   88705264 total
- age   7:     206808 bytes,   88912072 total
- age   8:     379752 bytes,   89291824 total
: 4972949K->103466K(6116736K), 0,6467869 secs] 9718795K->4850150K(28136832K), 0,6491803 secs] [Times: user=1,98 sys=0,07, real=0,65 secs] 
Heap after GC invocations=17053 (full 7):
 par new generation   total 6116736K, used 103466K [0x00007fbac8000000, 0x00007fbc88000000, 0x00007fbcc8000000)
  eden space 4893440K,   0% used [0x00007fbac8000000, 0x00007fbac8000000, 0x00007fbbf2ac0000)
  from space 1223296K,   8% used [0x00007fbc3d560000, 0x00007fbc43a6a960, 0x00007fbc88000000)
  to   space 1223296K,   0% used [0x00007fbbf2ac0000, 0x00007fbbf2ac0000, 0x00007fbc3d560000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 22020096K, used 4746684K [0x00007fbcc8000000, 0x00007fc208000000, 0x00007fc2c8000000)
 Metaspace       used 61660K, capacity 64298K, committed 64804K, reserved 65536K
}
2019-10-08T09:32:55.534-0300: 5849302,831: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0,6675161 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0,0007981 seconds
2019-10-08T09:32:57.564-0300: 5849304,861: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0,0295079 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0,0134677 seconds
2019-10-08T09:32:58.204-0300: 5849305,501: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0,0172410 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0,0007547 seconds
2019-10-08T09:32:58.222-0300: 5849305,518: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0,0167946 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0,0005972 seconds
2019-10-08T09:32:58.273-0300: 5849305,569: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0,0225247 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0,0068172 seconds
2019-10-08T09:32:58.289-0300: 5849305,585: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0,0154409 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0,0006444 seconds
2019-10-08T09:32:59.307-0300: 5849306,604: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0,0180956 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0,0035842 seconds
```

I have 48Gb RAM in my nodes with `Xms=28Gb` and `Xmx=32Gb`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not error message, It is verbose gc log.

Comment: What is your question? This is, as Gasol said, the JVM telling you that it had to invoke GC to free up some memory - and nothing else. While it did that, the JVM had to pause executing for a tenth of a second. This is probably not noticeable in any way for your cluster.

Comment: After these events, a knot falls and stays for about 50 minutes, then comes back without doing anything.

It seems to be some operation you are doing, how can I identify?

Comment: clusterstatus my node it's down. But after it's come back (without any intervation)